# Reordering given child components by drag and drop

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a list of given child components that i want to order by drag and drop.

```
<app-1-card [input]="input" />
<app-2-card [input]="input" />
<app-3-card [input]="input!" [input]="input"/>
<app-4-card [input]="input" />
```

I cant realy change them. I tried to order them with viewchildren, but that didn't work because they have no index i think. I thought about wrapping them in an other component to order them but i dont know how exactly.

After ordering them with dnd i want to save the order as an array to use next time.

I tried ordering them with viewchildren but then dnd never got the index and knew where to put the component.

Comment: did you try using DragDropModule:  https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples#cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group

like this

<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
  <app-1-card cdkDrag [input]="input"></app-1-card>
  <app-2-card cdkDrag [input]="input"></app-2-card>
  <app-3-card cdkDrag [input]="input!"></app-3-card>
  <app-4-card cdkDrag [input]="input"></app-4-card>
</div>

Comment: Yes i tried it, but they dont reorder if i release them. sth is undefined. They got a previous and a current index, but dont swap.

Comment: please add some code so we can debug this issue in more detail ts code where you are handling the inputOrder and onDrop function

Comment: `<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">  <app-1-card [input]="input" />
<app-2-card [input]="input" />
<app-3-card [input]="input!" [input]="input"/>
<app-4-card [input]="input" />  </div>`  and `drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }` that's basicly the whole code

Comment: i think my main problem is, that i dont have the components in an array, that i can change. most tutorials work that way.

Comment: I have made some modifications to your code below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the way you're handling the input property in your child components.

```
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <app-1-card cdkDrag [input]="input" [index]="0"></app-1-card>
  <app-2-card cdkDrag [input]="input" [index]="1"></app-2-card>
  <app-3-card cdkDrag [input]="input" [index]="2"></app-3-card>
  <app-4-card cdkDrag [input]="input" [index]="3"></app-4-card>
</div>
```

In each child component, add an index input property to help track their positions in the array:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-1-card',
  template: '<div cdkDrag>{{ input }}</div>',
})
export class App1CardComponent {
  @Input() input: string;
  @Input() index: number;
}
```

And similarly for other components (app-2-card, app-3-card, app-4-card).

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  moveItemInArray(this.input, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```